# Find the speed of an object given two vectors

Tags: trigonometry

Here's the question:  An airplane flies horizontally from east to west at 304 miles per hour relative to the air.  If it flies in a steady 50 mile per hour wind that blows horizontally toward the southwest (45$^{\circ}$ south of west), find the speed and direction of the airplane relative to the ground.

I solved this problem on MyMathLab, so it's looking for a specific answer.

Here's my drawing of the vectors (not to scale):
[image: vectors of plane and wind]

The first answer I gave was $339.36$ mph.  I calculated this by adding the plane's speed relative to air ($304$mph), to the $i$ component of the wind vector, which I calculated as $25\sqrt{2}$ because $\cos(45)=\frac{i}{50}$, so $50\cos(45) = i$.  MyMathLab said this was incorrect, so I went back to the drawing board to see what I missed...  Then, I thought that you're supposed to instead subtract the $i$ component of the wind vector since the planes speed was relative to the wind.  So I then gave an answer of $268.64$ ($304 - 25\sqrt{2}$).  MyMathLab marked this as wrong also.  Finally I tried playing with the rounding.  It asked for the answer to be rounded to the hundreds place which I originally did, but instead I rounded my first answer to the thousands just to see.  That was my last attempt, so it revealed the aswer as 341.19.

I'm really scratching my head because it's so close to what I originally got that I'm thinking what I did was correct, but maybe not and it is just a coincidence that the answer I originally got, and the correct answer were so close.  Can anyone tell me if I solved it correctly and MyMathLab is just on drugs?

I should also note - I made sure my calculator was set to degrees, and I checked my answer several times.

Comment: I think it helps to draw the wind vector at the head of the airplane velocity. The 339.36 number comes from the horizontal component only. When you sum the square of this and the vertical component and then take the square root you get your final answer.

Comment: AHHH!  That's what I was not understanding...so I just didn't draw it correctly.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to include the vertical component of the wind. Since it's an isosceles right triangle, note that $i$ and $j$ have the same magnitude, so the magnitude of the resultant vector is:
$$
\sqrt{(304 + 25\sqrt 2)^2 + (25\sqrt 2)^2} \approx 341.1921
$$